# SFMC busines rule to auto update all subscribers email address

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have a few subscribers who has changed their email addresses in our system which has been reflected in synchronized data extensions in Marketing Cloud. On email send SFMC is sending email to their old email addresses. Upon investigation, I found that All Subscribers data has not been updated with the new email address for the subscribers who changed their email addresses in Salesforce Cloud (CRM).

Please find below the details for one of the records.

```
Subscriber Key: 000000000000BBBAA1
New Email address (changed on 13/12/2016): NEW@test.com 
Old Email address: OLD@test.com
```

I have raised a case with SFMC and they came up with a solution to enable the business rule in our account to update the records in All subscribers data as soon as the record is updated in CRM.

Can someone help me to understand the impact of this business rule going forward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The email address Salesforce Marketing Cloud uses on send depends on your [**Data Sources**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/contact_builder/data_sources/) in [**Contact Builder**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/contact_builder/).
You can configure these setting to have Salesforce use an email address in a Data Extension in place of the one in All Subscribers.

Alternatively, you can force an update on the affected subscribers in All Subscribers by conducting a [**Data Extract**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/data_extract_activity/) activity, followed by a [**File Transfer**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/file_transfer_activity/) and then [**Import**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/import_activity/) activity - choosing to Import the data into the All Subscribers list.

These steps can also be put into Automation Studio and scheduled to run daily.

Comment: Hey Cameron, SFMC can enable a business to rule to auto update subscribers list when the record is updated in Salescloud. I just wanted to check if we can get the history of the old email address whenever we need?

Comment: Hi Cameron - curious on your first option? 
Based on what i've been told, it isn't really on option. There are two send methods in marketing cloud - email studio and journey builder. 

Email studio sends are based on the email in All Subscribers, always. Journey builder is based on channel address orders.

you can overcome a lot by letting triggered sends, journey builder etc. update the value in all subscribers, but, if you want a live update, you would have to leverage a salesforce apex trigger that updates all subscribers in marketing cloud, to my knowledge?

Comment: Hey Kenneth, You're right about address order, however I wasn't aware of it's limitations. It was a recommendation during implementation that we used both of the above solutions to overcome out of date email addresses between our "CRM" and SFMC; which is not Salesforce-CRM. My 2nd solution appears to have been identified as the answer for [this question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/145314/issue-with-using-contactid-as-subscriber-key-in-marketing-cloud).